# Slow Apache Server on EasyPHP

Tags: performance, apache, easyphp

I am using the EasyPHP DevServer 13.1 VC9 (which has Apache 2.4.4 VC9, MySQL 5.6.11, PHP 5.4.14, PHPmyadmin 3.5.8.1 and xdebug 2.2.2). The Apache server is very moody! Sometimes it works fine, but at other times the pages take ages to load. How do I get around this?
I am developing on my local machine. I am a newbie and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

its easy,
added these lines into httpd.conf (you can added these lines anywhere in httpd.conf)

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: Could you give us some info about what those lines do ?

Comment: it's working great now... thanks

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to use the IPv4 version of 'localhost' in my hosts file.  The 'hosts' file is usually located in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` directory on most systems. Editing the 'hosts' file was a pain in the neck. You can't simply right click or double-click to open the file. You first have to fire up Notepad or your favorite editor using "Run As Administrator" (right-click) and then hunt for the file using the "File -> Open" dialog. Windows prevents editing that file normally (a good thing) but then get in the way of actually editing it (a bad thing).

Anyway, under Windows 7, the following two lines are commented out:

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost
```

Uncomment the first line but leave the second commented:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost
```

Save the file. Try loading pages in Apache again. Should be back to normal speed.

Source :
http://cubicspot.blogspot.fr/2010/07/fixing-slow-apache-on-localhost-under.html

Comment: Thank you so much. This is good and worked for me